# "Performing Offline Audio Processing" example using AVAudioEngine to process to a .wav file does not work

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioengine

For context, I have been following along on Apple's documentation at. You can download the code there to reproduce this problem.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/audio_engine/performing_offline_audio_processing?changes=__6&language=objc.

Essentially, I am trying to transform a .wav file to another .wav file using AVAudioEngine.

In the example, I am using this instead of Apple's code. Just using a .wav file.

```
let sourceFile: AVAudioFile
let format: AVAudioFormat
do {
    let sourceFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "totransform", withExtension: "wav")!
    sourceFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: sourceFileURL)
    format = sourceFile.processingFormat
} catch {
    fatalError("Unable to load the source audio file: \(error.localizedDescription).")
}
```

and then when I try to convert it, I am using this instead of Apple's code. Attempting to convert to a .wav file. This is where I am running into issues.

```
let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: engine.manualRenderingFormat,
                              frameCapacity: engine.manualRenderingMaximumFrameCount)!

let outputFile: AVAudioFile
do {
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let outputURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("output.wav")
    outputFile = try AVAudioFile(forWriting: outputURL, settings: sourceFile.fileFormat.settings)
} catch {
    fatalError("Unable to open output audio file: \(error).")
}
```

Now, when I have "output.wav" the file cannot be played. However, if I use "output.caf" everything works well

My question is, how can I do offline rendering like in the Apple example and have the output file be a ".wav"?

I have tried converting the buffers between formats, but to no avail. I think this is the direction I need to take, but I am not sure exactly how to do this.